# Tkinter function "root.after()" doesn't run the function specified

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When I use the Tkinter function "root.after()" it only runs the function specified once. In my case this is the "move" function, in the line second from the bottom of my code. Overall, I'm trying to just do a basic animation to an oval.

I'm running Python 3.7.1.

```
from tkinter import *

class shape:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.EdgeThickness = 1
        self.color="#ffffff"


    def animation(self,xposgiven):        
        self.shape = self.canvas.create_oval(xposgiven,250,250,400,fill=self.color,width=self.EdgeThickness)
        print('runninganimation')


root=Tk() 
c=Canvas(root, width=1000, height=500)
c.pack()
c.configure(background="#000000")

s=shape(c)
s.xpos=5

def move():
    print('runningmove')
    s.xpos+=5
    s.animation(s.xpos)

root.after(100,move)
root.mainloop()
```

I expected that the function move() would run every 100 ms but it only runs once. I thought the function root.after(time,func), ran the function 'func' every 'time' ms. But it doesn't appear to be doing this in my code. It only runs once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`after` schedules a job to run exactly once. If you want it to run every 100ms, a common strategy is to have your function call `after` with itself as an argument before returning.

```
> import tkinter
> help(tkinter.Tk.after)
after(self, ms, func=None, *args)
    Call function once after given time.

    MS specifies the time in milliseconds. FUNC gives the
    function which shall be called. Additional parameters
    are given as parameters to the function call.  Return
    identifier to cancel scheduling with after_cancel.
```

Comment: Thank you. I just moved the root.after(100,move) into the move() function, then called move() after the definition of the move() function. It worked perfectly :) Also, I just learnt how to use "help" in python too. :D